# ajax and ruby script only returning 1 record instead of many

Tags: ruby, ajax, postgresql, sinatra

I am doing an Ajax call, using Ruby and Sinatra. The query should return multiple rows, it only returns one though.

The ajax script is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".showmembers").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('script');
            var short_id =  $('#shortmembers').val();
            console.log(short_id);
            $.getJSON(
                "/show",
                 { 'id' : short_id },
                function(res, status) {
                        console.log(res);
                $('#result').html('');
                $('#result').append('<input type=checkbox value=' + res["email"] + '>');      
                $('#result').append( res["first"] );
                $('#result').append( res["last"] );
                $('#result').append( res["email"] );
                    });
        });
});
```

and the Ruby script is:

```
get '/show' do
id = params['id']
DB["select shortname, first, last, email from shortlists sh JOIN shortmembers sm ON sm.short_id = sh.list_id JOIN candidates ca ON ca.id = sm.candidate_id where sh.list_id = ?", id].each do |row|
    @shortname = row[:shortname]
    @first =  row[:first]
    @last = row[:last]
    @email = row[:email]
    puts @shortname
    puts @first
    puts @last
    puts @email
    halt 200, { shortname: @shortname, first: @first, last: @last, email: @email }.to_json
    end
end
```

If I run the query directly in the terminal on postgres I get 9 rows returned but, as above on my website, it just returns the first row only.

What's the problem? No error in the console, just one record.

Comment: thanks, I have tried status 200, { etc.} and status 200 {etc.} and just the hash {} none of them work. What should it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `halt 200` inside your loop.  This will cause Sinatra to terminate the request processing and return the result back up the stack.

To return a full set of results, you will need to do something like the following:

```
get '/show' do
    id = params['id']

    results = DB["select shortname, first, last, email from shortlists sh 
                  JOIN shortmembers sm ON sm.short_id = sh.list_id 
                  JOIN candidates ca ON ca.id = sm.candidate_id 
                  where sh.list_id = ?", id].map do |row|
        {
            :short_name => row[:shortname],
            :first=>row[:first],
            :last=>row[:last],
            :email=>row[:email]
        }
    end

    halt 200, results.to_json       
end
```

This will return the selected fields from each row as an array of hashes.

In fact, as I look at the above, the solution might even be as simple as:

```
get '/show' do
    id = params['id']

    results = DB["select shortname, first, last, email from shortlists sh 
              JOIN shortmembers sm ON sm.short_id = sh.list_id 
              JOIN candidates ca ON ca.id = sm.candidate_id 
              where sh.list_id = ?", id]

    halt 200, results.to_json
end
```

since you don't seem to be selecting anything but the columns you desire in the first place.

Comment: thanks, I have tried status 200, { etc.} and status 200 {etc.} and just the hash {} none of them work. What should it be?

Comment: thank you very much the ruby code works great. Now I ma having a dreadful problem using the jquery to get the data back into nicely formatted HTML on the web page! Will keep you posted. Any cool suggestions?

Comment: the data in the console comes back as [{"short_name":"Ariba: Senior Solutions Consultant", ..etc}] and I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to reference it and append it to the div on my HTML page.

Comment: thanks. How do I then format the returned hash into HTML? getJSON this['email'] etc. dos not work!

Comment: Sorted, thanks. I will put the jquery code up too as it may help somebody else.